# Posting JSON strings with Kohana 3.2 in PHP

Tags: php, json, post, kohana

When running normal post operations I use the following code:

```
 $request = Request::factory($url)->method(Request::POST)->post($params);
 $response = $request->execute();
```

I'm not sure what it is I need to change though to enable me to POST a json string instead of an array variable.

My json string is basically created using the json_encode() function on an array of parameters, like so:

```
$params = array(
    'var1' => $var1,
    'var2' => $var2,
    // etc
);

$json = json_encode($params);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found these solutions.

Using PUT:

```
$request = Request::factory('http://example.com/put_api')->method(Request::PUT)->body(json_encode('the body'))->headers('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

Using POST:

```
$request = Request::factory('http://example.com/post_api')->method(Request::POST)->body(json_encode('the body'))->headers('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

From here: http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/requests#external-requests

Comment: The `Request::PUT` should not be necessary. PHP only knows POST or GET. You only need to set the response headers so the browser will fetch it as JSON. The same header would need to be set if you wanted to use, for example, XML or PDF.